# Check out data between 2 dates in search functionality in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

In my database table, I have 1 field `date_created` with datetime datatype.

In my front view,`from` and `to` date is there.
In from-> 05/01/2014 and in to ->05/01/2014
and I click on submit button.

Then my query is like this:-

```
$from_date          = $_POST['from'];
        $to_date            = $_POST['to'];
        /*Changed Date format as Database*/
        $from_date              = new DateTime($from_date);
        $new_from_date          = $from_date->format('Y-m-d');
        $to_date                = new DateTime($to_date);
        $new_to_date            = $to_date->format('Y-m-d');
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id =37 AND DATE_FORMAT( date_created, '%Y-%m-%d' ) >= '2014-05-15' AND DATE_FORMAT( date_created, '%Y-%m-%d' ) <='2014-05-15'
```

Then no record found is coming. In database there is record of 15 date. Why it is not coming?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are doing it wrong. Your input dates are 05/01/2014 format you need to convert it to Y-m-d before using it to query.

Comment: try as `date(date_created) between '$from_date' AND '$to_date'`

Comment: i have tried between but its not working .@AbhikChakraborty

Comment: can you echo this query and share what you get `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id =37 AND date(date_created) between '$new_from_date' AND '$new_to_date'` also input date is in m/d/Y or d/m/Y ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id =37 AND date(date_created) between '2014-05-15' AND '2014-05-15' @AbhikChakraborty with no record found.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52807/discussion-between-user1988-and-abhik-chakraborty)